# Hibernate returns invalid results with composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite-key

I'm getting the strangest results. I have a class with a composite key.
If i do the following query:

> from LOVEJB l order by l.canonicalId
>   desc

my results are not ordered by the '**canonicalId**' column I asked for. Instead, the canonical id result is like:

> 823 823 822 823 ,,,

Can someone give me some pointers on how should I try to crack this? I already messed up with *hashcodes* and *equals*, I experimented with a new class, etc. to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried ordering by a field within your id, like 'canonicalId.field'? just to see if that orders properly?

Comment: Also maybe post some of your .hbm.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out. My composite key had columns that were not part of the table's primary key. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

What's the actual QUERY generated? Order is dictated by RDBMS.
Turn on show_sql in Hib configuration and run that query manually.